# JPA query with sorting by ElementCollection gives UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When there an entity which has an `ElementCollection` field of a simple type, and on trying to have query using sorting of that field, there is an `UnsupportedOperationException`

```
public class SomeParent {
  @ElementCollection
  private List<String> keywords;
}

public interface SomeParentRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeParent, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SomeParent> {

  @Query("select sp from SomeParent sp")
  Page<SomeParent> findBySomething(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Calling the custom query with the field sorting, gives an error:

```
var pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 20, Sort.by("keywords"));
someParentRepository.findBySomething(pageable);
```

However, calling [findAll()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html#findAll(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)) (with sorting by the field) works fine:

```
var pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 20, Sort.by("keywords"));
someParentRepository.findAll(pageable);
```

and also calling the custom query with no sorting works fine.

```
var pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 20);
someParentRepository.findBySomething(pageable);
```

I tried adding `@OrderBy` to the field, but it doesn't help.

I hope there is a way other than using [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/specifications.html), as the real-life query has more parameters.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.PluralValuedSimplePathInterpretation.accept(PluralValuedSimplePathInterpretation.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSortSpecification(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3764) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSortSpecification(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3745) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.renderOrderBy(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3351) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitOrderBy(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3335) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:3086) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.visitQuerySpec(PostgreSQLSqlAstTranslator.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.select.QuerySpec.accept(QuerySpec.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.visitSelectStatement(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:988) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translateSelect(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:851) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.AbstractSqlAstTranslator.translate(AbstractSqlAstTranslator.java:801) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.buildCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:372) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:518) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:367) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:204) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:137) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy248.findBySomething(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Page<Feed> findBySomething(Pageable pageable);`

to

`Page<SomeParent> findBySomething(Pageable pageable);`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the reason. The question has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use "nativeQuery" about the sort.So i will give you an example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM some_parent ORDER BY keywords ASC", nativeQuery = true)
Page<SomeParent> findBySomething(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is an error that `keywords` column doesn't exist. And on changing the query to `select * from Some_Parent sp, some_parent_keywords k where k.some_parent_id=sp.id ORDER BY k.keywords ASC` and changing the column in Pageable, still an error happens.